# Problem launching streamliit script from terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, streamlit

I am having a problem when I try to launch my streamlit script from vs code or mac terminal.

I get the following error:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'streamlit': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

A normal python file runs it with no problems:

[image]

My Python version installed is 3.7.3.

I also have streamlit installed on the computer:

[image]

This happens to me from the mac terminal and from the vs code terminal.

I don't quite understand what is going on. I have changed computers recently and so far it always worked.

I hope you can give me some idea where the problem might be!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which command you use to run but this is the correct format;

```
streamlit run /Users/PATH/app.py
```